# Only use cart of current store in multistore setup

Tags: php, magento

I am using a multistore setup and have an issue regarding using the same session after login.

- Site 1 : http://testsite.com/store1
- Site 2 : http://testsite.com/store2

If login with the same user and password and add a product to the cart, that product is showing up in  both stores carts.

If I add something to the cart, it should only show in the store site in which I added the product, but not in the other store. What do I need to do?

Comment: Sessions (and cookies) are generally handled on a per-domain basis. It would be much easier for you, especially in a multi-store environment if you separated them out into subdomains. That way you can set the cookie domain paths in your core config data table to reflect each subdomain. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Main domain is same. It is not possible to change sub domain. urls are different only. 1) http://store1.testsite.com 2) http://store2.testsite.com. can you please guide me for the solution. Admin panel is also same of both of the site.

Comment: Which do you have? Folders or subdomains? You've suggested both now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There is only one folder as subdomain ie. http://store1.testsite.com and in that other store was created having url http://store2.testsite.com

Comment: You should set your cookie domains for each store then. It should work out of the box like that.

Comment: Is there other way to differ the session? As separation of domain is not possible.